# agregar campo faltante en lista llena

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

como puedo agregar un dato faltante a un campo de una fila cuando la lista ya esta llena?, ya que si agrego a la lista con el metodo ADD se agrega una nueva fila o registro.

Se agega nuevo registro con Add

```html
    List<ExtraParameters> ips = obj.IPS;
    ExtraParameters a = new ExtraParameters();
    a.SAN = obj.SAN;
    ips.Add(a);
```

y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que necesito es que pueda agregar el campo faltante a mi lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu lista, es una lista de objetos.

Cada uno de esos objetos, tiene sus campos.

Si uno de los objetos no tiene datos, simplemente debes cambiar el objeto. No tenes que agregar un objeto nuevo. Tenes que buscar el objeto que queres cambiar, referenciarlo, y simplemente cambiar el valor.

Para buscar el objeto en tu lista, supongo tendras un ID o forma de encontrarlo. por lo tanto, podrias buscarlo usando linq

```
var result = ips.where(x => x == idabuscar);
```

Y luego, simplemente, modificarlo

```
result.SAN = obj.SAN;
```

Esto va a modificar el objeto que vos queres, porque simplemente estas obteniendo una referencia a el.